# cURL works but browser doesn't work for Node Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running a NodeJS application that connects to MongoDB via the mongooseJS driver. It is hosted on AWS and managed by OpsWorks using Monit to keep the application alive.

The issue I'm having is that when I first deploy my application it works fine. But after an hour or so, if I try to load the application in the browser the request times out and I never get a response from the server.

I thought that the application had crashed and monit wasn't working, but that isn't the case. Even though I can't ping the server via a browser or using Postman, the application is in fact running and I can use cURL to successfully ping the server.

When I restart the application it starts working again, for a while at least.

Why does cURL work, but the browser doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chasing this issue for a while I finally figured it out. The issue was that my application was disconnecting from my mongod process and not crashing or reconnecting.

If the application were to exit when disconnected from the database, Monit would restart it and all would be ok.

To solve the problem I added some logic for reconnecting to the database and exiting the application if not connected after some period of time.

Here's what my server.js file looks like now:

```js
'use strict';

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Dependencies

var http = require('http'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    chalk = require('chalk');

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Variables

var initialConnection = true,
    connected = false,
    reconnectTries = 30,
    reconnectInterval = 1000;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Start Server

function startServer() {

    console.log(chalk.green.bold('\nSTARTING SERVER'));

    // initialize express application
    var app = require('./server/express.js')(mongoose);

    // start http server
    http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
        console.log(chalk.green(' application started on port '+process.env.PORT));
    });

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Stop Server

function stopServer() {

    console.log(chalk.red.bold('\nSTOPPING SERVER'));
    console.error(chalk.red(' '+new Date()));

    if (connected) {
        mongoose.connection.close(function () {
            process.exit(0);
        });
    } else {
        process.exit(0);
    }
}

process.on('SIGINT', stopServer);

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Timestamp

console.log(chalk.bold('\n********************'));
console.log(chalk.bold('\nSTARTING APPLICATION'));
console.log(' '+new Date());

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Environment Variables

console.log(chalk.blue.bold('\nENVIRONMENT VARIABLES'));

[
    {var: 'NODE_ENV', default: 'development'},
    {var: 'PORT', default: '3000'},
    {var: 'DB_CONNECTION', default: 'localhost'}
].forEach(function(env) {
    if (!process.env[env.var]) {process.env[env.var] = env.default;}
    console.log(chalk.blue(' '+env.var+'='+process.env[env.var]));
});

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Database Connection
// - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html
// - http://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-connection-best-practice/

console.log(chalk.cyan.bold('\nCONNECTING DATABASE'));

// create connection
mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://'+process.env.DB_CONNECTION+'/signal-noise',
    {
        server: {
            auto_reconnect: true,
            reconnectTries: reconnectTries,
            reconnectInterval: reconnectInterval
        }
    }
);

// success
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    if (initialConnection) {
        console.log(chalk.cyan(' connected to mongodb at ' + process.env.DB_CONNECTION));
        initialConnection = false;
        connected = true;
        startServer();
    } else {
        console.log(chalk.cyan.bold('\nRECONNECTING DATABASE'));
        console.log(chalk.cyan(' connected to mongodb at ' + process.env.DB_CONNECTION));
        console.log(chalk.cyan(' '+new Date()));
        connected = true;
    }
});

// error
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.error(chalk.red.bold('\nERROR: Could not connect to MongoDB.'));
    console.error(chalk.red(' '+err));
    console.error(chalk.red(' '+new Date()));
    stopServer();
});

// disconnected
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.error(chalk.red.bold('\nMONGODB DISCONNECTED'));
    console.error(chalk.red(' '+new Date()));
    connected = false;
    setTimeout(
        function() { if (!connected) { stopServer(); } }, 
        reconnectTries*reconnectInterval
    );
});
```